# Httpclient ловит ошибку, которую не ловит "обычный" браузер

Tags: java, servlet, httpclient

Захожу httpclient-ом (четвертой версии) на некий адрес

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://мой_адрес");
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, context);
```

высветляет исключение:

```
org.apache.http.client.CircularRedirectException: Circular redirect to 'http://мой_адрес/что_то_еще'
```

В "обычном" браузере (мозилла, хром) на том же '**http://мой_адрес**' проходит все нормально, пересылает куда надо (хотя там тоже имеется возможность отлавливания зацикливаний, например, если искусственно создать такую ситуацию).

Может, кто сталкивался/знает, в чем может быть дело в общем случае? Может, есть возможность настроить httpclient, таким образом, чтобы игнорировал "нектритичные" зацикливания и можно было получить страницы за этим циклом?

**Обновление**

Прошу прощения, ошибся - в сообщении исключения другой адрес (на том же домене), нежели в первоначальной строке запроса (исправил). В браузере на первый запрос высвечивает статус 302 и не использует куки, далее куки формируются, но беда в том, что я даже не могу достать статуса и кук, т.к. исключение вылетает сразу при httpclient.execute(httpget, context);

**Обновление**

Установил заголовки в точности как в мозилле:

```
httpget.addHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
httpget.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
httpget.addHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
httpget.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0");
```

Установил конфиг в BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY (без него устанавливал в заголовке Cookie2: $Version=1 - не знаком с природой этих вещей, но в браузере не было)

Единственное отличие в Connection: Keep-Alive (большими буквами)

(запросы прогонял через прокси Fiddler'a.

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
.setProxy(new HttpHost("localhost", 8888))
.setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
.build();
```

Толку нет, проклятый клиент все выдает Circular redirect)

Comment: Возможно, сервер в первый раз выставляет cookie и редиректит на себя. Если ваш код не посылает cookie, сервер войдёт в бесконечный цикл.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @asianirish: Хм. Посмотрите HTTP-ответы в браузере (например, при помощи [вот этого](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/)), увидите, что шлёт браузер и чем это отличается от того, что шлёте вы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS, true);`

[Документация](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.2.x/tutorial/html/httpagent.html#d5e1169)

Я надеюсь это то, что нужно :)

Comment: Да, идея верная, я тоже сюда накопал, но в четверке (httpclient-4.x) это порицается и в таком виде вообще не работает, использовал вместо этого:

    //создаем конфиг с разрешением на циклический редирект
    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
    ...
    .setCircularRedirectsAllowed(true)
    .build();    
    
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setProxy(new HttpHost("localhost", 8888))//это не про это
    //устанавливаем конфиг с разрешением на циклический редирект
    .setDefaultRequestConfig(config) 
    .build();

Может кому пригодится.

Comment: @asianirish, хорошее замечение, спасибо